# Write Permission in android Webview

Tags: android, android-permissions

Can anyone help me in asking run time permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` when downloading a file from my application? Using `myWebview` in android which displays my website that I have PDF files in that, so I require run-time permission to allow storage access in my app.

Here is my sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings= mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://moh.org.in/");// Line of Code for opening links in app
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        mywebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, 
            String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    //Code For Back Button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

**Step 1.** Add permissions into your AndroidManifest.xml

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kotlinapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" 
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Step 2.** Write code logic inside MainActivity

- If the permission is not granted, show permission dialog, if users allow the permission, then download the file.
- If the permission is granted, then download the file

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC = 100;

    private WebView mywebView;
    private String url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://moh.org.in/");// Line of Code for opening links in app
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        mywebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition,
                                        String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                MainActivity.this.url = url;
                MainActivity.this.userAgent = userAgent;
                MainActivity.this.contentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                MainActivity.this.mimeType = mimeType;

                String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC);
                } else {
                    downloadFile();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void downloadFile() {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                downloadFile();
            }
        }
    }

    //Code For Back Button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @jaspreetsingh Glad to hear that, by the way if this answer solved the problem, then you can mark is an answer. It will help me improving my answers in the future. Happy coding =))